# Excel 2010 VBA: Auto width of DropDown combo

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, combobox, excel-2010

In Excel 2010, I have a worksheet with a dropdown combo. The combo is not an Active X, it as an form control. The combo takes its values from a table, and the table is re-filled by a vba macro, so the length of the values can change.

After updating the values at the table, I would like to re-size the width of the combo to the width of the longest value. I have searched a lot, but I can't find how to do it. I have found some examples, but I don't know how to translate them to my combo. For example, the following code (taken from http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=55098 ):

```
Dim iWidth As Double 
ComboBox1.AutoSize = True 
iWidth = 0 

For i = 0 To ComboBox1.ListCount - 1 
    ComboBox1.ListIndex = i 
    If iWidth < ComboBox1.Width Then 
        iWidth = ComboBox1.Width 
    End If 
Next 

ComboBox1.Width = iWidth 
ComboBOx1.AutoSize = False 
ComboBox1.ListCount = 0
```

would be translated to something like:

```
Dim iWidth As Double 
Dim mycombo as DropDown
Set mycombo = ActiveSheet.DropDowns("combo")
mycombo.AutoSize = True     ' <<<< no 'AutoSize' property in DropDown class
iWidth = 0 

For i = 0 To mycombo.ListCount - 1 
    mycombo.ListIndex = i 
    If iWidth < mycombo.Width Then 
        iWidth = mycombo.Width 
    End If 
Next 

mycombo.Width = iWidth 
mycombo.AutoSize = False    ' <<<< no 'AutoSize' property in DropDown class
mycombo.ListCount = 0
```

but there is no 'AutoSize' property in DropDown class.

Answer (score 0):

If your dropdown data is pulling from a table as you say, then all you need to do is autosize that table column and take the width from that (adding a bit (+20) to the end to allow for the dropdown box). See below example (if column the info is coming from is "C")

```
Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
x = Columns("C:C").Width
mycombo.Width = x + 20
```

Comment: The solution has 2 problems: 1. It requires the font size of the combo to be the same as the font size of the table (they look to be different sizes); 2. If the column of the combo is resized, then all cells in that column will be affected (and requires the combo shape to be configured as "fit to cells).

Comment: AFAIK, Form Controls cannot be resized based on the cells they are in, only "Move but don't size" and "Don't move or size". The font size could be an issue, but if you use VBA to get the font sizes for both, you can just scale x by that same factor. Only issue (that you havent mentioned but I just thought of) is font face being different

Comment: Actually, on testing, using `.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size` gives `NULL` on a Dropdown. Could always take the height of the dropdown as a decent representation though